Deleting files with full name of file from chunck name part
What I'm looking to do is remove duplicate files.
example of files:
2024-11-22 23-40-25 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-14-02 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-02-34 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-01-58 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt

I do:
def delete_all_duplicates(original_list_files,list_files):

    for file in list_files:
        if list_files.count(file) > 1:
            for filex in original_list_files:
    
                if file in filex:
              
                    try:
                        print('Trying to remove')
                        os.remove(filex)
                        print('file removed')
                    except:
                        pass

I don't care about the date. I just want to delete those three files and keep one.
I've tried a lot but nothing works. I suspect I need to use regex.
I just want to delete those three files and keep one.
I've tried a lot but nothing works. I suspect I need to use regex.

Change your first line to for file in set(list_files): to potentially reduce the number of loop iterations.

It should be a one-liner in your shell to rename all files with their existing name minus everything up to the first dash surrounded by spaces.

You can post your own answer, but please do so in an answer. Don't edit it into the question. Stackoverflow has a strict separation of questions and answers. That allows others to post alternative answers, and people can vote separately for questions and answers.

It's unclear to me why there are two lists of files as input to the function, while the example data is only one list. The code suggests that list_files is only needed for the count>1 check. But that entirely does not match the "delete three files, keep one" since all four filenames in the example are unique.

Hi everyone,
I finally solved this using the following code:
def delete_all_duplicates(newpath,original_list_files, list_files):
for file in list_files:
if list_files.count(file) > 1:
for filex in original_list_files:
if file in filex:
try:
os.remove(newpath+filex)
except:
pass
I know very well that this is not the right thing to do. There may be options to correct this in a more professional manner.


I suspect I need to use regex.

You can use them, but there are not necessary, observe that in
2024-11-22 23-40-25 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-14-02 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-02-34 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
2024-11-22 22-01-58 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt

datetime part is fixed width, so it is enough to slice name, for example you could do
import os
files = ["2024-11-22 23-40-25 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt","2024-11-22 22-14-02 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt", "2024-11-22 22-02-34 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt", "2024-11-22 22-01-58 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt"]
seen = set()
for file in files:
    name_without_dt = file[19:]
    if name_without_dt in seen:
        os.remove(file)
    seen.add(name_without_dt)

Warning: this solution assumes all filenames start with datetimes in shown format.

You can use a regex to find:

a bunch of digits and/or dashes, followed by
a space, followed by
a bunch of digits and/or dashes, followed by
a dash surrounded by spaces

and replace that with nothing, i.e. delete it
import re

files = ["2024-11-22 23-40-25 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt",
         "2024-11-22 22-14-02 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt",
         "2024-11-22 22-02-34 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt", 
         "2024-11-22 22-01-58 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt"]

for f in files:
   dateless = re.sub("[\d-]* [\d-]* - ", "", f)
   print(dateless)

Output
Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt
Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt


Note that this is a little less "brittle" than simply deleting the first N characters and will continue to work with filenames like:
2024-7-4 2-14-59 - Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd).txt


Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I can continue with more code to complete the task of removing duplicates. The trick is that all the files contain the same information, so it doesn't matter which of the files is worth not deleting.

The only diference between the first and second code is the newpath so I suppose the list has only the filenames.
The os.remove() method requires the absolute path of the file to be removed, that's the reason the first code does not work.You should be more specific about the files to be removed to get a better answer:

if the numbers between the date and the rest of the filename are important to select the files to be removed
if all the files to be removed have "Konstrukteur - MÃ¶bel (mwd)"
what files are in the original_list_files list

If the second code works than this is a more elegant way to do the same:  
def delete_all_duplicates(newpath, original_list_files,  list_files):
    files_to_remove = [file for file in list_files if (list_files.count(file) > 1) and (file in original_list_files)]
    for file in files_to_remove:
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.join(newpath, file))
        except OSError as error:
            print(error)

